# Twitter - award a user for following

Tags: redirect, twitter, twitter-follow

I am building a site that has a points system for the user.  I would like to award them points if they follow the site on Twitter but don't really know where to start.

In essence I would like the following to occur:

1. User clicks link inside of admin that takes them to twitter
2. They follow the site
3. Once followed it redirects them back to the site

Anyone got ideas on where to find a guide on this?

Thanks
Nick

Comment: Simply have each user enter their twitter id as part of their profile or some such. Then you would just check to see if the entered handle is in your followers group, if so award points to the corresponding user. The twitter api has lots of examples to see followers, etc. If you get stuck with something specific then ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out web intents @ https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents#tweet-intent - it has sample code. Also logon on to your twitter account and go to https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#mention  the first one is probably the one you're most likely to use though.

Good luck!

Rachel :)

Comment: as for rewarding them you  might have to set up a boolean if followed is true then give reward or something like that....

Comment: Thanks for that Rachel.  Having taken a quick look its not really what I am looking for but I will explore it further before giving a full response in here.  Thanks for the prompt feedback.  Cheers Nick

Comment: Oh hang on, you maybe onto something with your first link!  I'll let you know.